# Array do tipo Object dúvida a respeito das referências

Tags: java, array

```
package testeJavaUtil;

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Conta conta[] = new Conta[2];
    for(int i=0;i<conta.length;i++) 
    {
        Conta contaPessoal = new Conta();
        if(i==0) {
            contaPessoal.setNomeDaPessoa("Ola mundo");
        }else {
            contaPessoal.setNomeDaPessoa("Mundo ola");
        }
        
        conta[i]=contaPessoal;
        System.out.println(conta[i].getNomeDaPessoa());
    }
  }
 }
```

Estou com dúvida a respeito do array do tipo object conta[], se cada posição de um array do tipo object é uma referência para o objeto contaPessoal. Cada vez que array mudar a posição  a contaPessoal não seria sobrescrita e logo a saída não seria as duas iguais (por causa do conteúdo na memória)? A saída gerou "Ola mundo" na posição conta[0] e "Mundo ola" na posição conta[1]. Por que isso acontece? O que acontece no espaço de memória alocado com a objeto contaPessoal?

Answer (score -2):

A cada vez que mudar a posição da repetição será criado na memória um novo objeto através new Conta() .
O array conta[] irá receber uma referência de uma referência através de conta[i]=contaPessoal

> (contaPessoal é uma referência para o novo objeto criado e não propriamente o objeto).

Por isso que cada mudança de posição no array ocorre como o resultado "Ola mundo" na posição conta[0] e "Mundo ola" na posição conta[1]. Cada posição do array é uma referência para objetos diferentes.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).